# How To Run my Application in Background in Android?

Tags: android

actually i have created application it contains:-
one layout on which i have  two text boxs and one button.as i press on button then my progress bar got started on dialog box..and i have called to next activity(message dialog box) as progress bar got reached to maximum value dialog message is displayed..
but i want to run this in background and as i am playing with another applications then also my message dialog must displayed on current application......right now dialog message is getting popup in my application only. please help to achieve it.....

--Thanks in Advance....

Comment: Take a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3674662/how-to-run-a-task-in-background-in-android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try looking into [Service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) and [Notification](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html). You can't create dialogs that display over other activities as far as I know. You might want to check out [Notifying the User](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/index.html).

From the Service docs:

> A Service is an application component
>   representing either an application's
>   desire to perform a longer-running
>   operation while not interacting with
>   the user or to supply functionality
>   for other applications to use.

Comment: then what i wanna to use here???is notification will be steady on current application? i guess its toast  message.

Comment: public class MyService extends Service {
 
 
 @Override
 public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
  return null;
 }
 
 @Override
 public void onCreate() {
Intent i = new Intent(MyService.this, CustomDialogExample.class);
        startActivity(i);
 //Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  
 }

Comment: this is what i written in my service class..is dis right...???please help me.....